# Moment.js filtering only before day 12

Tags: javascript, datatables, momentjs

I have a datatable and using moment for filtering date. My problem is if i enter days before day 12 is working fine but after day 12 not filtering my data. For example the date between 01/01/2021 and 12/01/2021 is working fine but if i enter 01/01/2021 and 13/01/2021 not getting any data.

```
// Extend dataTables search
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
            function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                var min = $('#min-date').val();
                var max = $('#max-date').val();
                var createdAt = data[0] || 0; // Our date column in the table
                moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');

                if (
                    (min == "" || max == "")
                    ||
                    (moment(createdAt, 'DD/MM/YYYY').isSameOrAfter(min, 'DD/MM/YYYY') && moment(createdAt, 'DD/MM/YYYY').isSameOrBefore(max, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
                ) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        );

 function dtConvFromJSON(data) {
            if (data == null) return '1/1/1950';
            var r = /\/Date\(([0-9]+)\)\//gi
            var matches = data.match(r);
            if (matches == null) return '1/1/1950';
            var result = matches.toString().substring(6, 19);
            var epochMilliseconds = result.replace(
                /^\/Date\(([0-9]+)([+-][0-9]{4})?\)\/$/,
                '$1');
            var b = new Date(parseInt(epochMilliseconds));
            var c = new Date(b.toString());
            var curr_date = c.getDate();
            var curr_month = c.getMonth() + 1;
            var curr_year = c.getFullYear();
            var curr_h = c.getHours();
            var curr_m = c.getMinutes();
            var curr_s = c.getSeconds();
            var curr_offset = c.getTimezoneOffset() / 60
            var d = curr_date.toString() + '/' + curr_month.toString() + '/' + curr_year.toString();
            return d;
        }
```

Iam using dtConvFromJson function here ;

```
  "columns": [
                { "data": "Date", render: function (data, type, full) { return dtConvFromJSON(data); }, "autoWidth": true },
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show how and where you use the `dtConvFromJSON(data)` function? Also, what `data` do you pass into that function? (A guess: Is "day 13" being handled as a month-of-year number, not as a day-of-month number, somewhere?)

Comment: I edited question. I think so "day 13" being handled as a month-of-year

Comment: What `data` do you pass into that function? Can you show us some of the source JSON data?

Comment: Date: "/Date(1609016400000)/"

Comment: Thank you for your updates. I tested with one row of data, using the following JSON: `[{ "Date": "/Date(1609016400000)/" }]`, and with two `<input type="date"...>` fields.  Filtering  worked as expected. I am not able to recreate your problem. You may need to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed to problem.

I have changed my  function dtConvFromJSON(data)  function to

```
 function dtConvFromJSON(data) {
  return new Date(parseInt(data.replace('/Date(', '')))
}
```

and voila! Works now!